# how to search xml file and display the string using xpath and display them on dgv

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

i have created an c# application in which i have to load the .resx file and display the contents on dgv and load a .tmx file and display the translation for the string. For example

```
<body>
    <tu tuid="880">         
        <tuv xmllang="fr-FR">
            <seg>Sélectionner un contact</seg>
        </tuv>
        <tuv xmllang="de-DE">
            <seg>Kontakt auswählen</seg>
        </tuv>
        <tuv xmllang="en-US">
            <seg>Choose Contact</seg>
        </tuv>
        <tuv xmllang="es-ES">
            <seg>Elegir contacto</seg>
        </tuv>
    </tu>
```

I have loaded the dgv and displayed the English stirngs in Source Column .If the column "Source" in dgv contains "Choose Contact" i have to display "Elegir contacto" in "Target" column. For now i have used the following code

```
XPathDocument doc;
XPathNavigator nav;
XPathExpression strExpression;
XPathNodeIterator iterator;
doc = new XPathDocument(OpenDialog.Filename);
nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
strExpression = "/body/tu[tuv/seg='Choose Contact']/tuv[@xmllang='fr-FR']/seg";
iterator = nav.Select(strExpression);
```

I am stuck after this line. I have to display the @xmllang value in the Target Column. How can I do this?

Comment: What is the logic behind mapping source column to target column? Can you explain it?

Comment: @codeninja :I have to translate the strings in source column to different language,for example "french". The logic is when I load the .tmx file of french language it should traverse the tmx file to locate the strings in source column and find its translation in tmx file and display it in target column

Comment: Break down your problem into small steps. Let this question solve problem of getting corresponding translation from the XML, then if necessary, open new question for displaying the string in target column. Is that ok? Do you have to stick with XPathDocument or XmlDocument is also an option? The latter is simpler to use IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with XPathDocument so i have chosen XmlDocument for this approach

```
string givenString = "Choose Contact";
string language = "fr-FR";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string filePath = "sample.xml";
doc.Load(filePath);
string path = "//tuv[seg='" + givenString + "']";
XmlNode rootNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(path).ParentNode.Clone();
string childPath= "//tuv[@xmllang='" + language + "']";
XmlNode node = rootNode.SelectSingleNode(childPath);
Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
```

--SJ